# Formly plugin place attribute inside table broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the plugin http://thrivingkings.com/formly/ does not show the "place" text when inside a table td tag. Cannot for the life of me find a way to make it work.

Example code:

```
<form>
<table>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="test_form" place="form" size="30px">
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: have not used the plugin, but one advice, try writing placeholder="form" instead of place"form"

Comment: answer it and ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes..As Andy said and I thought the plugin is expecting you to provide only direct children of form...
In that case if some more attributes are needed to be defined just define them directly..

As in this case add placeholder="text" instead of place=""..

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this plug-in before, but the plug-in contains the following code:

```
this.children().each(function(index, item)
        {
        // Placeholder text
        if($(item).attr('place'))
```

This looks like it expects the input elements to be direct CHILDREN of the form tag - and not hidden deeper inside tables.

Comment: thanks, @Rajat Singhal advised me to use placeholder="" instead of place="", which worked